# delete all files in folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, yeoman

how to delete files in project catalogue during yeoman process?

```
initializing() {
    this.sourceRoot('./generators/templates');
    this.destinationRoot('./generators/project');

    console.log(this.destinationPath());
    console.log(this.sourceRoot());

    this.fs.delete(this.destinationPath());
    this.fs.delete(this.destinationPath('**/*'));
    this.fs.delete('project');
    this.fs.delete('./generators/project');
    this.fs.delete('generators/project');
    this.fs.delete('generators/project/**/*');
}
```

non of these seems to work :(

Comment: What about `this.fs.unlinkSync('yourpath')`?

Comment: unfortunately that method is undefined

Comment: `non of these seems to work` - do you get any errors?

Comment: no error at all. even if I provide not existing path

Answer (score 4):

```
   fs.readdir('path here', (err, files) => {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            for (const file of files) {
                fs.unlink(path.join('path here', file), err => {
                    if (err) console.log(err);
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: missing `const path = require( 'path' );` @see https://nodejs.org/api/path.html

Answer (score -4):

If you want to delete a file using fs you should use `fs.unlink(path, callback)` or `fs.unlinkSync(path)`.

```
// Asynchronous version
fs.unlink('file.txt', function(err) {
    if(!err) {
        console.log('file deleted');
    }    
}

// Synchronous version, deprecated
fs.unlinkSync('file.txt');
```

Make sure you have the newest version of node installed to make sure this is available.